# handlebars template source change

Tags: handlebars.js

for some reason (translation) i need to change some of the text in script, so is there any kind of option to do that with javascript? so, for example below how i would change text "room type"?

```
<script id="simple-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">      
        <div class="row booking-detail-row">
           <div class="col-sm-3"><label><strong>Room Type</strong></label></div>
           <div class="col-sm-9">{{roomTypeName}}</div>
       </div>
</script>
```

Kind regards,
Jure

Answer (score 0):

To do translations properly, you will want to modify your templates to treat the label text as data rather than straight text.

So your template would look like this (in the example you provided):

```
<script id="simple-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">      
        <div class="row booking-detail-row">
           <div class="col-sm-3"><label><strong>{{roomTypeLabel}}</strong></label></div>
           <div class="col-sm-9">{{roomTypeName}}</div>
       </div>
</script>
```

Now, you would need to either update your data stream or intercept it in JavaScript prior to applying your template. To do this in JavaScript here's a working sample of how you might accomplish it:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="rooms"></div>

<script id="simple-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="row booking-detail-row">
        <div class="col-sm-3"><label><strong>{{roomTypeLabel}}</strong></label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">{{roomTypeName}}</div>
    </div>
</script>

<script>
    function translate(prop, lang) {
        switch(prop) {
            case 'roomType':
                return (lang === 'en') ? 'Room Type' : 'Type de chambre';
                break;
            default:
                return (lang === 'en') ? 'Unknown' : 'Inconnu';
        }
    }

    function addRoomType(roomTypeData, template, lang) {
        roomTypeData.roomTypeLabel = translate('roomType', lang);
        document.getElementById('rooms').innerHTML = template(roomTypeData);
    }

    $(function() {
        var data = { roomTypeName: 'Kitchen' };
        var source   = $("#simple-template").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        addRoomType(data, template, 'fr');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this example, but what i need is to modify this template through JS if this is even possible. Unfortunately I do not have access to template. We use some existing software where some translations needs to be done at some pages. Updates of this software are annually and contact the developer team to change it is not an option. So i need little bit hacking to do something to translate it:) Is this even possible?